# make_scorer giving an error: 'str' object is not callable make_scorer

Tags: python, string, typeerror, grid-search

I am using the following code to optimize a random forest algorithm but this is throwing a typeerror: 'str' object is not callable. Could you please help me in identifying what could be the cause? The fit line is throwing the error in the scorer.py file for this one "score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)"

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, make_scorer
clf_scorer = make_scorer('roc_auc')
rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,oob_score=True)
param_grid = {
    'max_depth':[4,8,12],
}

cv_rfc = GridSearchCV(estimator=rfc, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, 
scoring=clf_scorer)
cv_rfc.fit(train_data,target)
```

Following is the code from cross_validation.py that's giving the error:

```
def _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer):
    """Compute the score of an estimator on a given test set."""
    if y_test is None:
        score = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    else:
        **score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)**
    if hasattr(score, 'item'):
        try:
            # e.g. unwrap memmapped scalars
            score = score.item()
        except ValueError:
            # non-scalar?
            pass
    if not isinstance(score, numbers.Number):
        raise ValueError("scoring must return a number, got %s (%s) instead."
                         % (str(score), type(score)))
    return score
```

Comment: That line is not in the code you've posted. Please post the actual code.

Comment: Also, please always post the stack trace of error. The actual code for error is a plus but not required always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your third line to:

```
clf_scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score)
```

The first argument, `score_func`, needs to be a callable scoring function.

Comment: Based on this link http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html    we should be able to input string 'roc_auc' as parameter for the scorer, right?

Comment: @AbhiGupta Yes you can, but not in make_scorer, you can use 'roc_auc' directly in gridSearchCV constructor.

Comment: Exactly. The string functionality unfortunately does not work on the make_scorer. Maybe it would be a good thing for them to add it in the future...